# Golang XML processing

Tags: xml, go, encode, unmarshalling

I am trying to process XML files with complicated structure in Go using the standart encoding/xml package, change values of couple of nodes and save the alternated file. For example:

```
<description>
    <title-info>
        <genre>Comedy</genre>
        <author>
            <first-name>Kevin</first-name>
            <last-name>Smith</last-name>
        </author>
        <movie-title>Clerks</movie-title>
        <annotation>
            <p>!!!</p>
        </annotation>
        <keywords>comedy,jay,bob</keywords>
        <date></date>
    </description>
</title-info>
```

And many more fields. I would like to change the node:

```
<author>
    <first-name>Kevin</first-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
</author>
```

to

```
<author>
    <first-name>K.</first-name>
    <middle-name>Patrick</middle-name>
    <last-name>Smith</last-name>
</author>
```

However, since files are massive and uses more then 50 tags I really don't want to describe the complete structure to unmarshal them, so I have

```
type Result struct {
    Title   string   `xml:"description>title-info>movie-title"`
    Authors []Author `xml:"description>title-info>author"`
}

type Author struct {
    Fname string `xml:"first-name"`
    Mname string `xml:"middle-name"`
    Lname string `xml:"last-name"`
}
```

for fields I need to work with, but don't know how to keep rest of the file untouched. Looks like I need to use xml.decode to select the nodes I need to change (like at http://blog.davidsingleton.org/parsing-huge-xml-files-with-go/ post) while skipping unneeded tokens to xml.encode, but I can't convert this puzzle to some code.

Comment: I'd say you might try looking at XSLT. May be [this](http://godoc.org/?q=xslt)? Unfortunately, this introduces a dependency on `libxml2`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a constraint that you only use the standard library?

If not, I'd recommend etree (https://github.com/beevik/etree) which puts a DOM on top of the standard library's XML processing. It has a basic xpath syntax to select nodes, and you can easily edit them once you have them.